# Set size of images in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, image-size

I'm a newbie in Android. When I tried to create my dashboard using grid view, in different screens the images became small. I tried various methods to zoom it. But nothing worked for me. Can anyone suggest a solution for me ? I've 8 icons in my dashboard. Also when we put images in drawable folders , `what is the size of images in each folder`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use auto resized images... [GridView with Auto Resized Images on Android](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/11/01/gridview-with-auto-resized-images-on-android)  may work for you.. This explains a way to create a GridView with two columns and auto resized images inside each view